# Why does minify-all fail with "cleancss not found" error unless I install cleancss via sudo?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, clean-css

When I run my `npm install` I can see that clean-css *is* installed! It shows in the directory correctly. No matter how many times I re-install, or even `npm install -g clean-css`, it keeps throwing the error.

*but* if I install clean-css as a super user, and then as a regular user run my npm script again, it works!

Why? How do I fix this?